# How to print content using AWK on particular line

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

If string "clientside" found on line number "n" , then content of line number "n-1" should be printed out.

for example, I want to print content of line number 12 i.e `/Partition/SSL_profile` when  I find the string `clientside` on the line number 13.

```
12: /Partition/SSL_profile
13:       context clientside
```

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the file?

Comment: they aren't , just looking for the content on the n-1 th line, just above the search string"clientside"

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

This would print previous record where `clientside` is matched. The second command prints record number, and previous record.

```
awk '/clientside/{ print prev;};{prev=$0}' file
awk '/clientside/{ printf "%s: %s\n", (NR-1), prev};{prev=$0}' file
```

These would print previous record as well as current input record(`$0`).

```
awk '/clientside/{ print prev; print $0};{prev=$0}' file
awk '/clientside/{ printf "%s: %s\n%s: %s\n", (NR-1), prev,NR,$0};{prev=$0}' file
```

When `clientside` is matched, this prints previous record saved in variable `prev` and then prints current input record(`$0`).

But this command will print duplicate lines.

```
$ cat file
/Partition/SSL_profile
context1 clientside 
context2 clientside
context3 clientside
```

Here the above command gives following output:

```
awk '/clientside/{ print prev; print $0};{prev=$0}' file
/Partition/SSL_profile
context1 clientside 
context1 clientside 
context2 clientside
context2 clientside
context3 clientside
```

Therefore the command should be changed to this to avoid duplicate lines.

```
 awk '/clientside/{ if(line!=prev_lineno) print prev; print $0; line=NR};
{prev=$0;prev_lineno=NR}' file
```

Comment: @xhienne. Yes I forgot one change. Thanks for edit that out.

Comment: awk '/clientside/{ print prev;};{prev=$0}'  - This exactly gives me what I was looking for . I tested each but this is the one I am looking to solve my problem. - Thank you very much sir. The Duplicate case is not happening in my scenario, but  very likely that could happen.

Comment: @KedarBhatia. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

to print **both** line (line above and srting found)

```
grep -B1 clientside file
```

where

- -B1 stand for before 1, use -B5 to print 5 line before

to print only line before (not that you have only one string, even if `clientside` appear twice)

```
grep -B1 clientside file | head -1
```

For all appearances, use an inverted grep to remove the matching lines and `grep`'s group separators:

```
grep -B1 'clientside' file | grep -v '^--$\|clientside'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/clientside/ {if (a && a !~ /clientside/) print a} {a=$0}' file
/Partition/SSL_profile
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e '/clientside/ {x;p;d;}' -e x file 
/Partition/SSL_profile
```

or POSIXly:

```
$ sed -n '/clientside/{g
1!p
}
h
' file
/Partition/SSL_profile
```